# Save order data in a plain text file

Tags: emails, ubercart

Just like the order data can be sent via email, I want to save the order data in a plain text file in a specific directory on the same server as the drupal installation.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Saving a file should be a fairly simple job with PHP. If you want to do it when an order is completed, you could make a conditional action for it, or use one of the hooks that's invoked when the order is completed.

If you have an concrete problems on how to do this, you should refine your question.

If you want to save the mail sent, this would hold the order info, you could create a custom module and use hook_mail_alter to get the mail text:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'uc_order_action-mail') {
    $message_text = $message['body'];
    // Code to save text as txt file here.
  }
}
```

By default the mail sent with ubercart is a HTML mail, so you might want to create your own text instead.

Whatever you do, you shouldn't alter Drupal or any of the modules, you should create your own module(s) that make the alteration. If you are new to Drupal development, you should read the [developer guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Comment: Thanks for giving your time.

My question is.... when a customer completes his order then an invoice is sent to him an a invoice mail is also sent to admin.
I need to save this invoice details on server.So in which module should i do changes?? and what code will be used.i am new to drupal.please help me

Comment: I have one more question.... 

In drupal 6,there is a option to set action on particular events,like when checkout is complete,an invoice mail will be sent to both customer and admin.And at that page some more action can be added,as drupal 6 provides.


Action: Execute custom PHP code
here i can add some php code that may create test file.You may use these variables in your custom PHP.
Variables availble .... 
 
$order        uc_order  Order
$account user Customer user account


Please give me some useful codes to generate text file containing all detail of order.

Comment: As per googletorp's suggestion for converting Ubercart's email to plain text, you might find drupal_html_to_text() useful: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_html_to_text/6